# Objective-C can't assign a NSInteger to an NSInteger variable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsinteger

This is going to seem like a really silly question but I can't figure out why I'm getting an error.

I have an instance variable declared as:

```
NSInteger *scopeSelected;
```

I'm using this variable to keep track of what scope has been selected in a UISearchDisplay controller using:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    scopeSelected=searchOption;
    return YES;
}
```

However, I keep getting thrown this warning at the assignment line:

> Assignment makes pointer from integer
>   without a cast

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? Isn't it just an NSInteger to NSInteger assignment?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`NSInteger` is an int

change:

```
NSInteger *scopeSelected;
```

to:

```
NSInteger scopeSelected;
```

Comment: can't believe i forgot about pointers. thanks a million falconcreek :)